# JSP Script Tag usage in remote production server which has no internet connection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

I am working with a dynamic web project, where some of my JSP files need to use Jquery scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

As seen in the above tags, i use absolute URLs that points to scripts from web(googleapis site).
I use the jquery scripts mainly to achieve autocomplete feature for one of the fields. The relevant js file for autocomplete is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/script/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

As seen in the above tag, the script src is relative URL, where i have already downloaded the script from the web(https://pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/lib/jquery.autocomplete.js)

My questions are,

1. Will the absolute URLs in the scripts tag (referring jquery.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js) work perfectly and serves it purpose when my web application is deployed as .war file into the production server remote, where there is no internet ?
2. I also tried downloading the jquery.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js into my relative folder paths resources/script, and gave the script tag as

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/script/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```

But this is throwing the error in chrome's developer console as below

```
> jquery.autocomplete.js:257 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
    at receiveData (jquery.autocomplete.js:257)
    at Object.success (jquery.autocomplete.js:329)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

3. Is there any restriction that makes such jquery scripts will work
   only when it is referred from its absolute source? but not when i
   download it to local folder ?

Suggestions for best practices in these cases, is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

- If you include ALL the jQuery files in the war, your relative URLs should work offline
- Your jQuery is ANCIENT
- The pengoworks autocomplete is using `$.browser.msie` which has been removed from jQuery - but it should still be there in 1.3

> This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.

- You can add it back using a $.browser polyfill or remove it by using another autocomplete
- Since you use jquery.ui, you have one available: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I recommend

- get rid of the pengoworks
- update your jQuery to 3.6 and ui to 1.12
- use the autcomplete from jQuery.ui if you are using other parts of jQuery.ui, if not, perhaps find a newer autofill
- download and include ALL files used by the project

Comment: Yes, i would try that, but this way i currently have required very less code change and straight forward. By the way do you have an answer for my question 1 ?

Comment: Please see update

Comment: Thanks for now i have removed msie token condition from jquery.autocomplete.js, then updated the jquery-ui.min.js to 1.12.1, that accomplished the autocomplete it existing way

Comment: But i am wondering why that msie error did not occur when I pointed to absolute URL referring it directly from websites sources

Comment: I cannot tell. If I load 1.3, $.browser.msie works. Perhaps you loaded a newier jQuery in your test?

Comment: but why have `jquery.autocomplete.js` at all if you have autocomplete in ui?

Comment: Ok, thanks @mplungjan. Main reason was to avoid much code changes that induce too many work and testing as the project is bit old and we had time constraint.